# Is there any other way to paint inside and outside the spline of Texture2D in C# Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanted to make this image.
[image]

In order to implement this, I have configured this code.

```
        Texture2D texture2D = new Texture2D(Width, Height);
        float step = (Width - Min_x) / (float)Height;
        for (int y=0;y<Height;y++)
        {
            //max = The last x coordinate inside the area at the current y coordinate
            int max = (int)(Min_x + (step * y));
            for(int x=0;x<Width;x++)
            {
                Color color =
                    x>max? //=Area Outside
                    Color.clear:
                    //=Area Inside. Divide the border and non-border areas.
                    y < border || //Down Border
                    y >= Height - border || //Up Border
                    x < border || //Left Border
                    x > max - border ? //Right Border
                    Color.red : new Color(1, 1, 1, A_Channel/255f);
                texture2D.SetPixel(x, y, color);
            }
        }
        texture2D.Apply();
        Target.texture = texture2D;
```

This code shows these results.

[image]

This result means that the y value is 0, and the x value inside the for statement is the result of the Width date intention (not the Color.Clear, even though it is outside the area).

To correct this I set the color of the pixel
 When specifying the y value, I set the temporary color to Color.Clear.
[image]

The bottom part of y == 0 is still colored. The part where the y value is negative has automatically changed color even though I did not specify it.

The size of the target RectTransform
 It matches the size of Texture2D that you have.
Is there something I missed? As a part to display an image, either RawImage or Image shows the same result.